# while using CGAffineTransform view size is different while clicking

Tags: ios, swift, layout, cgaffinetransform

[image]i want to add animation while clicking the view. while displaying first time its circle but when i Transform the view size changes. i was want to add animation while change background animation show be like change circle from center to its end of view.
my code

```
class ClickableView: UIControl {
  @IBInspectable public var selectedColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear{
    didSet{
      updateColor()
    }
  }
  override open var isSelected: Bool{
    didSet{
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
      }) { (finished) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
          self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        })
      }
      updateLayout()
      updateColor()
    }
  }
  @IBInspectable public var mainColor: UIColor = UIColor.white{
    didSet{
      updateColor()
    }
  }

  // MARK: - initializers
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addAction()
  }
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    addAction()
  }
  func updateLayout(){
    self.layer.cornerRadius =  self.frame.size.width/2
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.layer.borderWidth = 10
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

  }
  // MARK: - draw rect
  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    updateLayout()
  }
  @objc func touchUpInside(){
    self.isSelected = isSelected == true ? false:true
  }
  func addAction()  {
    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchUpInside), for: .touchUpInside)
  }

  private func updateColor(){

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { [weak self] in
      guard let strongSelf = self else{return}
      strongSelf.backgroundColor = strongSelf.isSelected == true ? strongSelf.selectedColor:strongSelf.mainColor
    }

  }


}
```

Comment: `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)` is supposed to change the size of the view.. what's your problem?

Comment: i want to add animation while clicking the view.. and  CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9) for that purpose and in animation chain i have change its size to actual size. by this code self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity. but when i do so its not circle